# RDLC Reportviewer - Showing every sub report in a single page and remove a blank page

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, rdlc, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

**Hello,**

I'm using a ***RDLC*** Reportviewer and I need to show every subreport in a single page it's possible??!, and i need to remove a blank page if a subreport doesn't have a data.

[Image - List have a multi subreport](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05YLo.png)

- Page break on every subreport
- Remove a blank page if subreport does not have a data

Help me, please...
Thanks you.

Comment: Can't really see what your issue is with that picture.  Could you clarify the question?  You want all of your subreports on the same page or each subreport on a new page?

Comment: @Steve-o169  each subreport on a new page

Comment: @Steve-o169 dddd